# Insertar registro con AJAX y generar audio

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, audio

Tengo la siguiente estructura de un simple registro de una entrada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente...

Insertar el registro y despues **generar un audio** y en la parte que dice **"test"** mostrar un mensaje.

Ya hago registros con el siguiente metodo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmpsb').submit(function(){
      var datos=$('#frmpsb').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"1Sinstertar.php",
        data:datos,
        success:function(r){
          if(r==1){

          }else{
            alert("Error.");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Tambien otro problema es donde muestra la foto y el numero de empleado en varias ocasiones no se actualiza conforme al ultimo registro ingresado y en la tabla si, no se si sea por que esa informacion la muestro con PHP y no actualiza conforme a la informacion mandada con AJAX, de la siguiente manera.

```
<?php
                            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dt_cafeteria");
                            // Associative array
                            $sql="SELECT * FROM dt_cafeteria.dt_registros ORDER BY datetimes DESC";  
                            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { 
                              printf ("<td scope='row'><center><img src='_img/unknown.png' class='rounded card border-left-success h-10 responsive' width='250px' height='180px' style='margin-right:5px' display: block;></center></td>");
                            }else{
                              printf ("<td scope='row'><center><img src='_img/".$row['numemp'].".jpg' class='rounded card border-left-success h-10 responsive' width='250px' height='180px' display: block;></center></td>");
                              printf ("<td scope='row'><center>".$row["numemp"]."</center></td>");
                              printf ("<td scope='row'><center>".$row["nombre"]."</center></td>");
                            } 
?>
```

Eso es lo que quiero lograr espero haber dado a entender mi duda y me puedan orientar.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. En la parte `success` de Ajax puedes modificar el elemento donde quieres mostrar la respuesta que vino del servidor y que se debe encontrar en `$r`.  Pero en ese código, haciendo `if(r==1){` no vas a lograr nada. Por otra parte, hablas de un audio, pero, ¿de dónde sacas el audio?

Comment: Aun no tengo como generar el audio, no tengo idea de como hacerlo, ahorita ya genero registros pero quier saber como mostrar un mensaje de "Registrado" en la parte donde marque "Test" al haber hecho un registro.

Comment: Ya te dije desde el servidor PHP tienes que devolver alguna clave que certifique que se creó el registro, lees la respuesta en el `success` y en base a ella imprimes `Registrado` u otra cosa en el elemento donde dice `Test`. En el código PHP actual veo que devuelves una imagen, no sé por qué, ¿también te interesa esa imagen para algo?  Si es así debes organizar la respuesta (preferiblemente en un JSON) y tratarla en el `succes`. No sé si te suena a chino, pero es algo muy básico sobre como funciona Ajax.

Comment: No entendi bien , pero quieres que cuando regrese "Registrado" se escuche tambien el audio de "Registrado" ?

Comment: Asi es @kiramishima

Comment: Ok, para la parte del audio podrias hacer uso del API de Audio de Javascript 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web_Audio_API 
Cuando el Ajax regrese el mensaje de exitoso podrias lanzar el audio.

Comment: Otra opcion es tener un elemento Audio de HTML5 escondido en tu pagina y cuando se lance el sucess del Ajax de jquery , reproduzcas ese audio :) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/audio

Son las 2 formas en que haría esa parte del audio :)

Comment: Solucione la parte de que la tabla y foto se actualicen sin problema cada que se hace un registro con "JSON', ahora mi dilema solo es como generar el audio cada que se envia el registro, puedo generar el audio cada que se presiona el boton registrar... pero no es la idea